# jQuery's data() attribute does not update when element data changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I wanna use jQuery's `data()` api to retrieve all the data attribute of an element. But the cache nature of this api is really annoying. Sometimes I need to change some data atribute of an element in javascript but the `data()` api always return the initial value of each data attribute. So I have to use the `attr()` to access each data attribute of an element to get its up-to-date value. Is there any way to overcome this cache thing and make `data()` always return the latest value every time I call it?

Comment: It's not a cache thing, `data()` stores data internally and does not change the data attributes, if you have to change the attribute for some reason you should be using `attr()`, but if you're using `data()` consistently to both set and get the data it shouldn't be an issue, as you'll get the right data.

Comment: _"Sometimes I need to change some data atribute of an element in javascript"_ - Why? If you need to store data against the element after the page loads you can use `.data('key','value')`. This doesn't store the data as an attribute, but so what?

Comment: @nnnnnn Every client side templating language ever builds DOM, which may include data attributes, and most likely does not do so with jQuery.

Answer (score 51):

The short answer is: **don't use jQuery .data() for dynamically set data attributes, unless you can guarantee that data attributes are always set by jQuery**.

Either solution below will work:

- Use vanilla JS `.getAttribute()` instead
- Use jQuery `.attr()` instead

Here's the [relevant part from the jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) (which I don't think really highlights how much this might surprise jQuery users):

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (**all data values are then stored internally in jQuery**).

Regarding why you might **not** use jQuery to set attributes: many client side templating languages build DOM, including data attributes.

Given the dynamically built HTML (as shown in DevTools:

```
<form data-test="300" ...
```

DOM API tells the truth:

```
 document.querySelector('form').getAttribute('data-test');
```

JQuery **returns an out-of-date previous value** (in this case, 19000):

```
 $('form').data('test');
```

jQuery `attr` returns the current value:

```
 $('form').attr('data-amount');
```

Vanilla JS `getAttribute()` returns the current value:

```
 document.querySelector('form').getAttribute('data-amount');
```

Comment: Great answer, sir. Thank you!

Comment: Absolutely correct answer. I was trouble a few hours for this issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use jQuery's [.removeData()](https://api.jquery.com/removeData/) method after updating the data attribute to reset its cache.

For example:

```
> document.querySelector('.sub-panels')
<div class=​"sub-panels">​…​</div>​

> document.querySelector('.sub-panels').setAttribute('data-test', 300);
undefined

> document.querySelector('.sub-panels')
<div class=​"sub-panels" data-test="300">​…​</div>​

> $('.sub-panels').data('test')
300

> document.querySelector('.sub-panels').setAttribute('data-test', 400);
undefined

> $('.sub-panels').data('test')
300

> $('.sub-panels').removeData();
[div.sub-panels, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: ".sub-panels"]

> $('.sub-panels').data('test')
400
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not bound to jQuery, you can use [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) to iterate over all attributes. Then it doesn't matter if they were added dynamically or not.

```js
const p = document.getElementById('test')
p.setAttribute('data-test', 300)

for (const attr of p.attributes) {
  // possibly filter with attr.name.startsWith('data-')
  console.log(`${attr.name}: ${attr.value} (is data-attr: ${attr.name.startsWith('data-')})`)
}

p.setAttribute('data-new', 400)

for (const attr of p.attributes) {
  // possibly filter with attr.name.startsWith('data-')
  console.log(`${attr.name}: ${attr.value} (is data-attr: ${attr.name.startsWith('data-')})`)
}
```

```html
<p id="test">Test</p>
```