# Pass parameters to shown.bs.modal function()

Tags: jquery, grails, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

How can I pass parameters to shown.bs.modal event? I'm current using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and I have the following codes:

```
function openAppForm(name, number) {

        $("#form-content").modal({cache:false},'show');

};

$("#form-content").on("shown.bs.modal",function (<<PASS name and number here>>) {
                  document.getElementById('apply-frame').src="${g.createLink(controller: "apply", action: "index")}?name=" + name + "&number=" + number;
            })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store these attributes on the element itself, then access them using the data function. This is how it's done on the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target).

```
function openAppForm(name, number) {
    $("#form-content").attr("data-name", name);
    $("#form-content").attr("data-number", number);
    $("#form-content").modal({cache:false},'show');
};

$("#form-content").on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    var name  = $("#form-content").data("name");
    var phone = $("#form-content").data("number");

    $("#apply-frame").attr("src", "${g.createLink(controller: "apply", action: "index")}?name=" + name + "&number=" + phone;
})
```

Comment: Had to change it to attr() instead of data() because data doesn't update when values for name or number has change. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588044/jquerys-data-attribute-does-not-update-when-element-data-changes

Answer (score 2):

when passing over fields I presume from your gsp as `name`, `number` in to the world of java script. From there on the functionality to bind with `g.something` a grails variable with a java script variable becomes impossible beyond what slightlyoverwhelmed has suggested by capturing and ending for example a given url.

So instead of doing something like that create the link the element id that is being clicking

```
<div class="form-content" 
data-url="${g.creatLink(controller:controller,action:action,params:[name:name,number:number]);">
```

then when clicked

```
 $('.form-content').on('click', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-url')
  //now giving it full url 
   openAppForm(url)
 })
```

Notice i changed id to class since this appears to be an instance of multiple rows which should not share the same id, they can share the same class and jquery will work out which class element from the `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more elegant ways, but you could try something like this;

```
var modalShow;
function openAppForm(name, number) {
    modalShow = function(name, number) {
        document.getElementById('apply-frame').src="${g.createLink(controller: "apply", action: "index")}?name=" + name + "&number=" + number;
    };

    $("#form-content").modal({cache:false},'show');
};        

$("#form-content").on("shown.bs.modal", showModal);
```