# get attribute value of parent <th> when anchor tag on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following table structure:

```
<th data-column-index="7">Total Activity Amount 
    <a class="btn btn-app btn-default filterStyle" onclick="getFilter(this)">
        <i class="fa fa-filter f_7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</th>
```

I need to get 'data-column-index' value when i click on getFilter() OnClick event. I already tried below method for getting parent value in Onclick event

```
function getFilter1(e){
    var evID=$(e).parent().find('data-column-index').val();
    alert(evID);
}
```

or

```
var evID =  $(this).parent('thead th').attr("data-column-index");
```

or

```
var evID = $(this).closest('th').attr("data-column-index");
```

All the causes i am getting same error like 'Error! Content not defined.'.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

**Please Note:**  'data-column-index' is dynamic value in J Query Data table and it automatically update while we change the position. So i can't directly add this value to On-click Event

Comment: Did you try with this `$(e).parent().data('column-index')` ?

Comment: Also you cannot use `this` as you haven't bound using jquery - you bind directly using onclick and you pass `this` into your function as `e`

Comment: @AliShahbaz. Sorry, i was not tried with that option. Now it's working. Thanks

Comment: @AliShahbaz Sorry, my 'column-index' is dynamically set data attributes. So i cant use the data(). Is there any alternative available?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with jQuery's [**`.data()`**](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

```js
function getFilter(e){
  $(e).parent().data('column-index', 8); // change the value
  var evID=$(e).parent().data('column-index');
  alert(evID);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th data-column-index="7">Total Activity Amount 
      <a class="btn btn-app btn-default filterStyle" onclick="getFilter(this)">
          <i class="fa fa-filter f_7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a>
    </th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Mamun, Thanks for your answer. It's working Now.I need one more clarification required. Without refreshing the page if i change 'data-column-index' value, that will get when i try next on-click event?

Comment: @BibinJames, I am not sure about the term *changing the value without refreshing page*. If the *data-column-index* value are changed by JavaScript then you will get the new value when click:)

Comment: Thanks Mamun. For above question we cannot use data() because my data values are dynamically change. don't use jQuery .data() for dynamically set data attributes.Insted we can use .attr() . My issue solved. Thanks
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588044/jquerys-data-attribute-does-not-update-when-element-data-changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest` method of jQuery to get the `th` column and then its attribute using `column-index`

```
function getFilter(e){
    var evID = $(e).closest("th").data('column-index');
    console.log( evID );
}
```