# select option for select element from data attribute using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select option for select element from value in select element data attribute..

```
<?php 
$selectval = 0;
?>

<select data-value="<?=$selectval?>">
<option value="1">yes</option>
<option value="0">no</option>
</select>
```

what I did in JQuery:

```
$('select').val($('select').data('value'));
```

but it is not working, I am still getting the first option as selected

**I also tried to print the value directly to value attribute also not working**

```
<?php 
$selectval = 0;
?>

<select value="<?=$selectval?>">
<option value="1">yes</option>
<option value="0">no</option>
</select>
```

*NOTE:*
I have more than one select element in the DOM and I want all of them to get values from data-attribute

Comment: Your code works in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1tp3j8ud/. Check the console for errors, ensure you're running the jQuery *after* the DOM has loaded, and ensure there's only 1 `select` element in the DOM.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have more than one select element in the DOM and I want to get value for all of them same as the example in my question

Comment: In that case you need to use a loop and address each on individually.

Comment: thank you i have inspired from you the solution, i did like this ```$("select").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).data('value'));
    });```

Comment: prefer using attr function instead of data function because [data function will cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588044/jquerys-data-attribute-does-not-update-when-element-data-changes)